# Reading php vars in js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a config file in PHP.

```
return array(
'window_width'      => 1000,
'window_height'     => 800
    //etc
);
```

How can I read these vars into my javascript? Should I echo them to the page, in perhaps a data attribute and pick them up from there? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
   var settings = <?php echo json_encode($your_array); ?>;
   alert(settings.window_width);
</script>
```

Comment: I would have hoped a 187k rep user like you would have gone searching for the obvious dupe, rather than the easy rep points.

Comment: because searching for the dupes takes longer than actually typing out that code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Echo them directly where you need them in javascript. You can echo a javascript object to reflect the data structure. Something like this should work:

```
var x = <?php echo '{window_width:"1000", window_height:"800"}'; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You should echo them to the page.

PHP runs on server, but JavaScript on client machine, browser. In PHP you should echo something like this:

```
<?php
echo('<script>var myvar = '.$myvar.';</script>');
?>
```